# Haskell - please help me simplify these two functions

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to work through the exercises in [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours). I need help with simplifying couple of functions.

```
data LispVal = Number Integer
             | String String
             | Bool Bool

isNumber :: [LispVal] -> LispVal
isNumber []               = Bool False 
isNumber [(Number _)]     = Bool True
isNumber ((Number _):xs)  = isNumber xs
isNumber _                = Bool False

isString :: [LispVal] -> LispVal
isString []               = Bool False 
isString [(String _)]     = Bool True
isString ((String _):xs)  = isString xs
isString _                = Bool False
```

The `isNumber` and `isString` functions have lot common structure. How do I go about factoring out this common structure?

Comment: Pattern matching can't be moved and factorized. So the String and Number literals must be written "on site". I'm not sure what you want to do, but you could maybe implement a `typeOf :: [LispVal] -> LispType` function that would pattern-match the expression once and for all and return its type.

Comment: You can remove the first case (empty list), as it is captured by the last pattern as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can't parameterize the pattern match itself, you can write yourself small helper functions so you at least don't have to repeat the list handling for every function:

```
isString (String _) = True
isString _ = False

isNumber (Number _) = True
isNumber _ = False

all1 _ [] = False
all1 f xs = all f xs

isListOfStrings = Bool . all1 isString
isListOfNumbers = Bool . all1 isNumber
```

In my opinion, the special case handling of the empty list isn't consistent here. You should consider just using `all` instead (so that the empty list can be a list of any kind, similar to how Haskell's lists work).

Comment: These give `Bool True` for an empty list, but the OP wants `Bool False` for that case.

Comment: @dave: Thanks... This doesn't make any sense, but I changed it.